# BackgroundWorker alternatives for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to do something like this in a Windows Forms app?

I'm trying to find other ways of updating the UI instead of using the BackgroundWorker all the time. Maybe something like this?:

```
public List<String> results = new List<String>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    When(SomeLongRunningMethod("get") == true)
    {
        // LongRunningMethod has completed.
        // display results on Form.
        foreach(string result in results)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = result; Location = new Point(5, (5 * DateTime.Now.Millisecond)); });
        }
    }
}

public void SomeLongRunningMethod(string value)
{
    if(value == "get")
    {
        // Do work.
        results.Add("blah");
    }
}
```

The above basically says, "Do *this* and when you're done, add the results to the form."

Comment: Look into async/await. Does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you use `async`/`await` with `Task.Run`. Note that *returning* the results is cleaner:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var results = await Task.Run(() => SomeLongRunningMethod("get"));
  foreach(string result in results)
  {
    this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = result; Location = new Point(5, (5 * DateTime.Now.Millisecond)); });
  }
}

public List<string> SomeLongRunningMethod(string value)
{
  var results = new List<string>();
  if(value == "get")
  {
    // Do work.
    results.Add("blah");
  }
  return results;
}
```

I have a series of blog posts on my blog that describe how [`Task.Run` acts as a replacement for `BackgroundWorker`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **async / await**:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = await SomeLongRunningMethod("www.stackoverflow.com");

    // LongRunningMethod has completed.
    ....
}

public Task<string> SomeLongRunningMethod(string uri)
{
    // Example
    return WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
}
```

An example for a compute intensive operation would be this:

```
public Task<string> SomeLongRunningMethod()
{
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
  {
     // Perform work which requires some time to complete ...
     return "your result";
  });   
}
```

There is lots of information on this topic in the web. Here is a link for an extensive introduction on the topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: I's suggest changing your async method names to end with *Async* and use `Task.Run` in favour of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: `.NET 4.0` does not have a `Task.Run` method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with async/await.
However, I suggest you also read a little on this topic before going in head-first.

```
public List<String> results = new List<String>();

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var results = await SomeLongRunningMethodAsync("get");
    //Flow continues here once the long running operation has completed
    foreach(string result in results)
    {
      this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = result; Location = new Point(5, (5 * DateTime.Now.Millisecond)); });
    }
}

public async Task<List<string>> SomeLongRunningMethodAsync(string value)
{
    //This is the long running operation
    //Mind you, this executes on a separate thread. 
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      List<string> results = new List<string>();
      if(value == "get") 
      {
        //do work
      }
      return results;
    });
}
```

More on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

As per @Daniel Kelley's suggestion below, it is indeed recommended to add the `Async` suffix to async methods. Also, `Task.Run` should generally be favored over `Task.TaskFactory.StartNew` because of automatic unwrapping of inner tasks (although that doesn't apply here, so I didn't adjust that as well).

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` is also longer than `Task.Run`, and has a potentially confusing default task scheduler. `Task.Run` is just superior all around, and should be used here. More info [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: `.NET 4.0` does not have a `Task.Run` method.